# Firebase Hosting - Hosted Flutter app not loading in some devices

Tags: firebase, flutter-web, firebase-hosting

I have facing some problems with Firebase Hosting for a few days. Since password reset link is linked to Firebase Hosting web address, some users cant open that link and can’t display that web page. Also I can’t open that page but my coworkers did open in their mobile devices and pcs. And since they can open that page, they successfully reset passwords, do recaptcha etc.

edit: I deleted the ss.

What is the solution for that problem?

Comment: Does this happen on a computer as well? If yes, try checking the console for any issues.

Comment: @Dharmaraj it was happening on my computer too but after 1-2 hours, it started working as usual. I don't know why it happened but I highly suspect it is related to Firebase Hosting service.